# Attaching Excel File to finished Visual Basic project

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I've created a Visual Basic project with many forms. In the project I write information to an excel file that I reference the location of on my local (C:) drive where the excel file resides. By reference I mean, I open an excel instance ten provide the source=local path on my hard drive. My question is how do I attach the excel file to the project so I don't have to reference the local location and can run the program on a different computer. In other words how do I bundle the excel file with the program? And how would I change the call to the excel file once I have it "bundled" to the program?

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of including the excel file with the program, maybe in a bin or something like that. Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: And when people say add a reference to my excel file, how exactly do I do that? I know how to get to the reference window where I can reference the libraries and etc, but how do I reference my excel file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the excel file to the project. Go to solution explorer and right click on the excel file and select properties. Change the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always. Now the file will be in the same directory as your exe. You can use `Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` to get the directory.

To add the file to the project:

Right click on project > Add > Existing Item > Your Excel File.xls

To include the file in build:

Right click on the file > Properties > Copy to Output Directory. Set this value to either Copy always or Copy if newer.

Here is the code to get the path to the excel file:

```
Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "Your Excel File.xls")
```

xlPath should now be the full path to the excel file.

Comment: Will this allow me to add to the file once I finalize the program? Where will I have to keep my excel file then?

Comment: It will be in the same folder as your exe when you compile it.

Comment: So wherever I take the finalize/published program it'll have the excel file with it? Also, how do I add the excel file to the project?         Note: I have to go to work, so I will not be able to reply further until 6 hours from now, but I will reply further once I get back tonight. Thank you so much for the help so far!

Comment: I included my excel file and changed the property. Now my next question is where do I put the piece of code you gave me in my program? I'm guessing it goes in whichever forms are referencing the excel file or I can declare it as a global dim (my choice I'm guessing). Now, how would I handle the excel file in the program now. For example, currently I work with the file using commands such as "sheet.Range("A1").Offset(row, column).Value()." Would I just replace sheet with xlPath or put xlPath.sheet....... sheet is what the excel sheet is declared as by the way.

Comment: Dim excel_app As Excel.Application
        Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim sheet_name As String
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
        ' Get the Excel application object.
        excel_app = New Excel.Application
        ' Make Excel visible (optional).
        excel_app.Visible = False

        ' Open the workbook.
        workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open("Path")
        sheet_name = "Sheet1"

        sheet = excel_app.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Will I need all of my excel file declarations still? Or would I still need them, but need to adjust them? If so, how would I adjust them. Right now my declarations are as I just posted. Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm need to handling this sort of situation as it's my first full-fledge program

Comment: The variable `xlPath` represents the path to the excel file. You would use `Workbooks.Open(xlPath)`

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you for your time, patience and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

**MODIFIED REPLY AFTER USER COMMENTS**

1) First create a Setting (named say `MyExcelFile`) to save the Name and Path of your excel file.

[image: Create Setting]

2) Now you can use `My.Settings.MyExcelFile` to refer to your excel file path.

3) If excel file is not found at the desired location, you can reset it by opening a File Open Dialog and asking the user to specify the file location.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not IO.File.Exists(My.Settings.MyExcelFile) Then
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls; *.xlsx"
        ofd.Title = "Specify Excel File Location"
        If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            My.Settings.MyExcelFile = ofd.FileName
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to be able to modify it at runtime to add the next record to the excel sheet. How would I accomplish that then?

Comment: If you need to modify it at runtime then you will need to keep the physical file (means not embedded in your EXE). If just referencing the path is your concern, then create an entry in `Settings` with whatever name you want; then access it in your code as `My.Settings.YourSettingName`.

Comment: I'm looking more in terms of attaching the file to the program. I'm thinking in terms of like how some programs include bins where they house files that the program uses. How could I do this?

Comment: For that you combine both the approaches I suggested. First include a predefined file in your Project Resources (`My.Resources`), and define a setting in Project Settings (`My.Settings`) for the file name. If file identified by your `My.Settings.FileName` exists then use that. Otherwise extract from your Resources to that location.

Comment: I already was able to attach the file via the Jeff's instructions, but thank you for offering your help

Answer (score 0):

i think iam not really getting what you mean but if you need to open the excel file with one click in the app and you dont want to write the path of the excel file (may be because you want you app portable) so the answer is to

1. put the excel file anywhere in the project folder
2. add existing item (`*.* filter`) and select the excel file
3. change the properties of the excel file build action: resource Copy to output directory:copy always
4. open the properties of the solution and click resources the drag the file and drop it
5. use the (`using system.reflection` & `using system.io` & `using system.resources`)

   then write the code like this

   ```
   string sPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
   File.WriteAllBytes(sPath, Properties.Resources.excel File name here);
   ```

then take that (`spath`) and use it as your path so then you can change the project location with the excel file inside it and it will still be working without writing a constant path for it